# Create Unix user that can read,write, execute in /opt/

Tags: permissions, accounts

I am setting up my cloud server and want to create a `Appliance` user on my Linux server that can install, read and write content on `/opt/` folder and few normal personal users that have only read access to `/opt/`. Any normal user if wants to install he/she needs to switch to `Appliance` user for the installation etc.
Please help me to setup the server with proper permissions.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to RW **only** in /opt? Is anywhere else acceptable?

Comment: @SiKing Given that this user can effectively have all the privileges they want (by installing a trojan in `/opt` which other users will then execute), there's no point in confining that user.

Answer (score 1):

```
adduser appliance
chown -R appliance /opt
```

Comment: I have added the user and also run "chown -R appliance /opt". But appliance user can't execute script from /opt/. it still giving error that you need root permission.